# Java regex space matches $ and * ??

Tags: java, regex, matching, replaceall

I'm not understanding something about how Java's regex matching for \s works. In the simple class below, \s seems to match [at least] $ and *, which is worrisome. When I don't include \s, the last char of each word gets chopped. And, neither regex seems to catch the ending " in the string. Would somebody please explain what's going on? Or point me to a useful resource? Thanks.

```
public class SanitizeText {

        public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                String s = "123. ... This is  Evil !@#$ Wicked %^&* _ Mean ()+<> and ;:' - Nasty. \\  =\"";
                String t = "123. ... This is  Evil !@#$ Wicked %^&* _ Mean ()+<> and ;:' - Nasty. \\  =\"";

                s = s.replaceAll(".[^\\w\\s.]", " ");   // Does the \s match non-space chars? Sees like at least $ and * are matched.
                s = s.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");

                t = t.replaceAll(".[^\\w.]", " ");              // Why does this regex chopping the trailing char of each word ??
                t = t.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");

                System.out.println ("s: " + s);
                System.out.println ("t: " + t);
                }
        }

// produces:
// s: 123. ... This is Evil $ Wicked * _ Mean and Nasty . "
// t: 123 .. Thi i Evi Wicke Mea an Nast "
```

Answer (score 2):

`\\s` does not match non-space chars.

The regex `.[^\\w\\s.]` will match `Any character, followed by a non-word, non-space, non-period character`.

It seems to work exactly like that to me.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to *Why does this regex chopping the trailing char of each word ??*

`.[^\\w.]` is matching any character (the `.`) followed by a non word, non dot character and repaces it by a space. So it matches each last letter in a word and the following whitespace.

Answer to *Does the \s match non-space chars? Sees like at least $ and * are matched.*

No. You are matching a char (`.`) followed by a non word, non whitespace character. So two characters each time.

```
.[^\\w\\s.]
```

will match on

```
Wicked %^&* _
 1.   ^^
 2.     ^^
```

and the `*` is not matched, because there is a whitespace following, therefor it is not replaced.